# Grails Fixtures / Build Test Data plugin not working within a Unit Test

Tags: grails, fixtures

I am trying to use the [Grails Fixtures Plugin](http://grails.org/plugin/fixtures) within a service unit test. I am using grails 2.2.

I have the next code in my BuildConfig.groovy

```
plugins {
    compile ":fixtures:1.2"
    compile ":build-test-data:2.0.3"
    ...
    ..
    .
}
```

Initially I tried

```
@TestFor(HotelService)
@Mock([Place])
class HotelServiceTests {
    def fixtureLoader 

    void testFixturesInUnitTests() {
        def fixture = fixtureLoader.build {
            hotel(Place, name: "Hotel Hilton")
        }
    }
}
```

The above test was failing:

```
|  java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke method build() on null object
```

With a Google Search I found in the [Grails User Mailing List](http://grails.1312388.n4.nabble.com/Grails-user-f1312389.html) that the fixtureLoader have to createdexplicitly inside the unit test.

```
  import grails.plugin.fixtures.*

  @TestFor(HotelService)
    @Mock([Place])
    class HotelServiceTests {
        def fixtureLoader 
        def grailsApplication

        @Before 
        void setUp() {
            fixtureLoader = new FixtureLoader(grailsApplication)
        }

        void testFixturesInUnitTests() {
            def fixture = fixtureLoader.build {
                hotel(Place, name: "Hotel Hilton")
            }
        }
    }
```

Test failed with the next error:

```
 java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke method hasGrailsPlugin() on null object
    at grails.plugin.fixtures.builder.FixtureBuilder.lookForBuildTestDataPlugin(FixtureBuilder.groovy:53)
    at grails.plugin.fixtures.builder.FixtureBuilder.<init>(FixtureBuilder.groovy:49)
    at grails.plugin.fixtures.Fixture.createBuilder(Fixture.groovy:75)
    at grails.plugin.fixtures.Fixture.build(Fixture.groovy:44)
    at grails.plugin.fixtures.FixtureLoader.build(FixtureLoader.groovy:46)
```

Another GoogleSearch and I found a 'hack' to avoid the previous error.

```
 import grails.plugin.fixtures.*
 import org.codehaus.groovy.grails.plugins.GrailsPluginManager
 import org.codehaus.groovy.grails.plugins.PluginManagerHolder

 @TestFor(HotelService)
    @Mock([Place])
    class HotelServiceTests {
        def fixtureLoader 
        def grailsApplication

        @Before 
        void setUp() {
            fixtureLoader = new FixtureLoader(grailsApplication)
            PluginManagerHolder.pluginManager = [hasGrailsPlugin: { String name -> true }] as GrailsPluginManager 
        }

        void testFixturesInUnitTests() {
            def fixture = fixtureLoader.build {
                hotel(Place, name: "Hotel Hilton")
            }
        }
    }
```

Now I am getting the next error:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke method isDomainClass() on null object
    at grails.plugin.fixtures.buildtestdata.BuildTestDataBeanDefinitionTranslator.translate(BuildTestDataBeanDefinitionTranslator.groovy:54)
    at grails.plugin.fixtures.buildtestdata.BuildTestDataBeanDefinitionTranslator.translate(BuildTestDataBeanDefinitionTranslator.groovy:43)
    at grails.plugin.fixtures.builder.FixtureBuilder.translateToBuild(FixtureBuilder.groovy:126)
    at grails.plugin.fixtures.builder.FixtureBuilder.invokeMethod(FixtureBuilder.groovy:121)
    at com.softamo.movilrural.TopRuralScraperServiceTests$_testFixturesInUnitTests_closure2.doCall(TopRuralScraperServiceTests.groovy:26)
```

I have no idea how to solve this. Any feedback is really welcome.

Answer (score 4):

The `fixtureLoader.build()` method integrates with the [Build Test Data plugin](http://grails.org/plugin/build-test-data). The fixtures plugin is intended to be used in conjunction with integration tests.

See also this issue http://jira.grails.org/browse/GPFIXTURES-21.
The `@TestFor` annotation marks test as unit, so you need to remove it.

File `/test/integration/com.example/HotelServiceTests.groovy`

```
    class HotelServiceTests extends GroovyTestCase {
        FixtureLoader fixtureLoader
        Fixture fixture
        void setUp() {
            fixture = fixtureLoader.load {
                build {
                    hotel(Place, name: "Hotel Hilton")
                }
            }
        }

        void testFixturesInUnitTests() {
            // given:
            HotelService service = new HotelService()
            // when:
            List<Place> hotels = service.list()
            // then:
            assert hotels.size() == 1
            assert hotels[0] == fixture.hotel
        }
    }
```

Hope it helps you.

Comment: Do I need to load fixtures on all of my tests? is the build method a way to use both `Fixtures` and `Build Test Data` plugins together? Thanks

Comment: Yes, method `build()` is added by Build Test Data plugin.
You can use `fixtureLoader` right inside of test method.
Also I would like to recommend you to write tests in (http://grails.org/plugin/spock)[Spock] instead of jUnit.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really an expert on fixture loader, but it seems you're just calling the wrong method (*build* instead of *load*).

```
@TestFor(HotelService)
@Mock([Place])
class HotelServiceTests {
    def fixtureLoader 

    void testFixturesInUnitTests() {
        def fixture = fixtureLoader.load {
            hotel(Place, name: "Hotel Hilton")
        }
    }
}
```

I haven't tried it, but you can look at the fixtures loader usage here: [Grails Fixtures Plugin - Reference Documentation](http://gpc.github.com/grails-fixtures/docs/guide/1.%20Introduction.html#1.1%20How%20It%20Works)

Comment: The previous approach did not work, because the fixtureLoader bean in not wired in Unit tests, but it does in integration tests.

Comment: As I said in the answer, I haven't tried it, thanks for reporting it. :)

Answer (score 0):

There is not really a way to support the use of fixtures plugin in a Grails Unit test.

You can achieve the same goals by using BuildTestData plugin, which provides the @Build annotation which supports the UnitTests.